# Pass pdf url to pdf.js in query string

Tags: node.js, pdf.js

I'm new to node/pdf js. I just install node and run pdf.js.

Now I want know how can I open pdf files using pdf js by passing pdf file url as parameter in query string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `?file=document.pdf` to the viewer url. See also https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/2496

Answer (score 1):

It will require some changes in the `viewer.js`:

- Move `parseQueryString: function pdfViewParseQueryString(query)` outside `var PDFView` so it's a standalone function: `function pdfViewParseQueryString(query)`
- Replace all occurences of `PDFView.parseQueryString(..)` to `pdfViewParseQueryString(..)`
- Change `var DEFAULT_URL = ''` to `var urlParm = pdfViewParseQueryString(document.location.search.substring(1)); var DEFAULT_URL = urlParm.url;`
- You should now be able to call the viewer with somethin like `$("actualViewer").src = 'pdfViewer?url=' + encodeURIComponent(pathToFile);`

Answer (score 0):

On a further note, it is important to know that the file=document.pdf argument must come before the hash sign:

http://myserver.com/web/viewer.html?file=test.pdf#page=6&zoom=page-fit,0,540

HTH